# Solidify Modifier Distortion on Walls of House

Tags: solidify-modifier

I am trying to add thickness to the walls of an apartment.
I used a simple plane and extruded geometry to match the layout and extrude the walls up.

Trying to add thickness via solidify mod leads to weird angles in the thickness of the walls.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your object, the inner walls are probably part of the same mesh as the outer walls, they should not because it will create a bad topology, therefore the deformations you show, here is what it gives if I apply the modifier:

[image]

You should better separate all the inner walls (select them and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to rip). Also don't forget to enable the *Even Thickness* option of the modifier. Now all the walls have the same thickness. Here is what it gives if I apply the modifier (you don't have to apply it if you have no reason to):

[image]